# Android Fonts in XML not working on 7.0

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-typeface

Hello everyone,
               I have used [Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html#using-support-lib) in xml for my app. It's working very well on android versions below 7.0. But not working on 7.0. I created a font folder inside drawable and put all my fonts in there. Then created a font family like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:font="@font/timeburnerbold"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/timeburnerbold"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
        android:font="@font/typo_grotesk_bold"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/typo_grotesk_bold"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="700" />
</font-family>
```

My Gradle file info

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "26.7.2"
supportLibraryVersion = '27.0.0'
```

And I m using this across the app. It's working perfectly across the app on 6.0 and below. But not on 7.0. Don't know what I m missing here. Anyone?

Comment: Please make sure you using same versions of all libraries, here you mentioned that compileSdkVersion is 27 so you need to use supportLibrary version 27.x.x

Comment: @AmrishKakadiya tried that as well,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very strange but I found the solution. Seems like a bug in SDK. In a font -family, If you have two fonts of different families like below xml ( My case )

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:font="@font/timeburnerbold"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/timeburnerbold"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
        android:font="@font/typo_grotesk_bold"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/typo_grotesk_bold"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="700" />
</font-family>
```

This type of file will not work on 7.0 to onwards.
Changing it to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:font="@font/typo_grotesk_regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/typo_grotesk_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
        android:font="@font/typo_grotesk_regular"
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/typo_grotesk_regular"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
        android:font="@font/typo_grotesk_bold"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/typo_grotesk_bold"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="700" />
    <font
        android:font="@font/typo_grotesk_bold"
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/typo_grotesk_bold"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="700" />
</font-family>
```

Really works on all api's. Same font family in one font family file. Don't know why it really happens.